# How can i make custom cursor in (C#)

Tags: c#, forms, bitmap, cursor

How can i make custom cursor for my application.

**This is my cursor:**

[image: Custom Cursor]

**My actually scripts:**

```
public BasePreview()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Bitmap bitmap = global::testCursor.Properties.Resources.Cursor1;
    Cursor cursor = new System.Windows.Forms.Cursor(bitmap.GetHbitmap());
    this.Cursor = cursor;
}
```

**Problems:**

Hovering the mouse over the program. So my cursor look as waitCursor. Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
System.IO.MemoryStream cursorMemoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(Properties.Resources.Cursor1);
Cursor mCursor = new Cursor(cursorMemoryStream);
this.Cursor = mCursor;
```

Comment: Errors:

Error 2 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'testCursor.Cursor'
Error 3 Cannot implicitly convert type 'testCursor.Cursor' to 'System.Windows.Forms.Cursor
Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'testCursor.Cursor.Cursor(testCursor.Cursor)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: and i used this:

Cursor mCursor = new Cursor("Cursor.cur");
this.Cursor = mCursor;

Comment: Edited answer check now.